# Dissolving redundant fields in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I have a map of a small neighbourhood. I'm trying to label these but because of the grid being squares the objects are split and therefore showing two two or more labels of each location.

I'm trying to use the dissolve tool to fix this but I must be doing it wrong.

First I open dissolve from geo-processing.

I input "Administrative text" as input features (the layer containing the names).

In the dissolve fields I've tried numerous ways but nothing has worked.

[image: Layer with location names visible]
[image: Disolve]

The attribute containing locations names is "TEXT".

Answer (score 1):

I do not think dissolve is the solution here. I think dissolving points with same TEXT values will create multipoints?

What you probably want to do is delete duplicates? You do not state what license level you are using (you should always state that) because if you have an Advanced license level then you can use the [Delete Identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm) tool.

The only issue I can think of, based upon you image above, is which text point do you want remaining, as looking at the image you have PORSON labelled in multiple places, which is the correct?

Answer (score 0):

An option actually would be to dissolve your featureclass checking the Create multipart features checkbox. When labelling you have to open the menu Placement Properties (Layer Properties - Labels - Other Options) and check Place one label per feature part.

If you use Maplex as labbeling engine (Data Frame Properties - General) you could also just check Remove duplicates (Layer Properties - Labels - Other Options - Label Density) w/o dissolving first.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you've listed so far, I think your best course of action would be to go to the properties for that layer and go to the labels tab. Then under the placement properties option you should find a 'Remove Duplicates' option. Once you check this option, it should keep your label field from displaying the same label more than once. If you still get multiples, then you want to open your attribute table and make sure that your entries are uniform for the different attributes.

Then to resolve the fact that some offshoot boundaries are separated from the main boundary for your entries, I would recommend going into your symbology screen and loading each unique entry as a separate value. This will allow you to set up unique symbology for each of the entries. Finally you can simply add a Legend to your map that distinguishes between the different symbology and will clear up any confusion when the map is viewed. I've attached an image of my desktop.

[image]